# Creating a New Form for content types in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, custom-form, form, list-form

This question is specific for SharePoint 2010.  I have one list with 2 site content types.  In SharePoint Designer, I can create a New Form and specify a content type for that specific New Form.  When I open the custom new form (From SPD or from the browser) every column from the list appears in the custom new form instead of the specific columns for that content type.  Similarly, if I delete the web part from the new form, and insert a custom list form (click Insert from the ribbon -> select SharePoint under the Controls group -> select Custom List Form -> specify the list and content type), I get the same result.  How can I create a custom new form for a list containing a site content type?

Comment: can you use Info Path ?

Comment: No InfoPath sir.  I am using SharePoint 2010 Standard.